# Python Relative import from parent directory when current script needs to run a main file

Tags: python, python-3.8, relative-import

I am working on a code where we have the following directory structure

```
base dir
|
--J
| |--C
| |  |--H
| |  |  |--M_task.py
| |  |
| |  |--C_task.py
| |  |
| |  |--A_task.py
|
```

All folders are packages.
I have two requirements:

1. I need to be able to import M_task module in A_task.
    That I am able to achieve using
   `from H.M_task import method`
2. import C_task inside M_task

In the second case I am facing several problems.
I can use absolute import when I am running the code on my local machine but it will not be possible to use absolute import when the code is deployed. So it is out of question.  
Using `from ..C_task import method` works only if I am using M_task only as a module. But I need to run M_task as script using main function in some cases. In that case, M_task does not have a parent folder and hence relative import does not work.

Last resort is appending parent folder to `sys.path`. But I want to avoid that solution as much as possible. Is there a cleaner way available to achieve what I want to here?

Comment: Did my answer solve it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did it by setting the PYTHONPATH and using absolute imports in the end.

Comment: That's the wrong solution - see below

Comment: We decided to change the folder structure in the end. That's why we went with absolute import. And yes we are using the base directory for absolute imports.

Comment: Absolute import is just fine - what I meant is that you should never run a script directly from its directory - you should always run from parent directory of topmost package using the `-m` switch. Absolute _and_ relative imports are meant to work seamlessly this way

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of running whatever you want is from `base dir` - so

```
$ cd "/path/to/base dir"
$ python -m J.C.H.M_task
```

The `-m` switch does the package detection magic - note you omit the py extension. It is an anti-pattern to run directly from the module dir cause of all the problems you faced.